# Combining multiple image descriptors (SIFT+HOG)

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, sift, feature-extraction

Can anyone clarify as to how mutiple image descriptors can be combined together. I mean , if I do a normal SIFT , then it gives me a 128xN matrix, where N is the number of descriptors. Now to add the HOG descriptor matrix which can be of a different dimension, what is the procedure (because simply concatenating them does not sound meaningful) ?. The final output of the combination would be used to create the bag of words model using k-means clustering.

Comment: what is the purpose of combining descriptors? to do image classification?

Comment: @rookiepig: Yes, it is specifically to improve classifications. I want  to avoid learning multiple kernels, as I have a huge dataset and I want to have faster computations.

Comment: Maybe this paper can help "[Gehler, ICCV09_code] - On Feature Combination for Multiclass Object Classiﬁcation". It has code available.

Comment: @rookiepig: As far as I can understand, they have applied the concept of multiple kernel learning, which is what I wanted to avoid. Anyway thanks.

Comment: @soumajyoti_sarkar SIFT and HOG both are used to extract local image gradient information at key points. They only differ in their feature descriptor dimension and normalization methods. Do you think that combining these two feature descriptors would do any significant impact on the final result? Did that improve the results in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating features does not sound meaningful but you should try. It is called "early fusion". And it can works.

Usually late fusion works better (learning the features separately and then merging the results/output of the two machine learning).

I tested it for [combining BoVW and BoW](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00946712), you should have a look in the paper, at section II, part C "multimodal fusion techniques".